# How to iterate in each element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/borsa/hisse-fiyatlari/"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
details = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"tBody"})
#print(type(details))

for detail in details:
    
    print("{} {}".format(
        detail.a.string,
        detail.find("li",attrs={"class":"cell004"}).text.strip()
        ))
```

We need to take the stocks with BeautifulSoup. Code only iterates the first element. How to iterate each one?

Comment: There's only one `div` with the `class` of `tBody`, what did you expect? You don't loop over each stock, you just `find` the first one, while you used `find_all` to find all `tBody` `div`s, even though there's only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find all `ul` elements and iterate over it to find title and values according to `class` wise and append items to `dict1` with key `title`

```
dict1={}
for ul in details.find_all("ul"):
    title=ul.find("li",class_="cell003 tal arrow").get_text()
    values=[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in ul.find_all("li",class_=["cell004","cell003"])][1:]
    dict1[title]=values
```

Now you can  use `pandas` module to transform data to DataFrame  using `pd.DataFrame` method and get data according to required

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df=df.transpose()

columns=[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find("div",class_="tHead").find_all("li")][1:]
df.columns=columns
```

Output:

```
           Son    Dün   ( % )   Yüksek  Düşük   Ağ. Ort  Hacim(LOT) Hacim(TL)
ACSEL   51,00   50,55   0,89    51,45   50,25   50,84   183.227 9.315.538
ADEL    22,98   22,98   0,00    23,20   22,72   22,93   67.600  1.550.269
.....
```